# In iTerm, why is a command shell's command not picking up things on my $PATH?

Tags: terminal, bash, command-line, iterm

I've got a script in my `~/.bin` directory that changes iTerm's background before starting an SSH session (as detailed [here](http://kpumuk.info/mac-os-x/how-to-show-ssh-host-name-on-the-iterms-background/), script slightly modified from [this version](https://github.com/kpumuk/dotfiles/blob/master/bash/bin/sshb)).

If I start a regular login session and run my command, `sshb servername`, it works fine! The background image loads and the SSH session starts.

However, if I set up a profile to start a session with that same command, it errors out and says it can't find `sshb`. If I make my command `~/.bin/sshb servername`, it runs the command, but says it can't find the ImageMagick `convert` command used in that script.

It seems as though the command shell command doesn't know about my `$PATH`. I suppose I could figure out where `convert` lives and edit the script to use the full path, but that seems to be treating symptoms, not the problem. Is there a way to make the command shell load my environment variables before it runs that command?

Comment: what do you et if you `echo $PATH` in the terminal session and where do you set your path (the info should be in the question not on an external site that could change etc)

Comment: If I `echo $PATH` in a normal terminal, I get `/Users/lannyh/.bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin`. If I make the Command Shell command `echo $PATH`, it prints the literal string `$PATH` and terminates the shell with a dialog notice about quickly-closing shells. I linked to the script above because the exact contents of the script are almost certainly not pertinent to my question; do I need to delete that parenthetical?

Comment: If `echo $PATH` returns `$PATH` there is most probably an error in one of the startup files for bash. Did you have a look at them already?

Comment: No. There's not a problem with the `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` because everything works fine with a login shell; the PATH is set correctly and everything's hunky-dory. It's only a problem with these iTerm command shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables like PATH and TERM are normally inherited from the shell. When you run the script directly, they are unset.

You can run the script as a child process of a login shell by setting the command to `bash -lc "~/.bin/sshb servername"`.

Comment: I must confess that my understanding of this is still on shaky ground. If I open up a terminal window, I get the whole shell environment to run a command from. What is iTerm *actually* doing that runs the command without the whole shell environment? Is it possible for me to do the same thing myself, manually, somehow?

Comment: You can use `exec -c cmd` to replace the process of the shell with `cmd` and clear the environment. Normally when you open a shell, iTerm 2 executes `login -fp username`, which runs the default login shell as a child process. If for example you set the command executed in new shells to `/usr/bin/emacs`, emacs won't have bash or any other shell as a parent process.